# createAsyncThunk unable to dispatch rejected action in MERN application

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I am working on one MERN application and using Redux toolkit to handle asynchronus task on react side.

I noticed that whenever I tried to sign-in in app with invalid credential, `createAsyncThunk` is unable to dispatch rejected action.

However, in network request I am getting error response with status **code 404**, but I am getting payload `undefined` in rejected lifecycle.

Is there any solution to fix that problem with `createAsyncThunk` ?

**controller(sign-in) :**

```
export const signin = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const oldUser = await UserModal.findOne({ email });

    if (!oldUser)
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "User doesn't exist" });

    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(password, oldUser.password);

    if (!isPasswordCorrect)
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid credentials" });

    const token = jwt.sign({ email: oldUser.email, id: oldUser._id }, secret, {
      expiresIn: "1h",
    });

    res.status(200).json({ result: oldUser, token });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong" });
  }
};
```

**authSlice.js :**

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";
import * as api from "./api";

export const login = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/login",
  async (formValue) => {
    const response = await api.signIn(formValue);
     return response.data;
  }
);

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    user: {},
    error: "",
    loading: false,
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [login.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [login.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.user = action.payload.result;
    },
    [login.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.payload.message;
    },
  },});
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

**Unable to get payload in case of failure**

[image: in debug mode]

**But getting response in network tab**

[image]